# Cypress not finding innerText though it's definitely there

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I'm testing an error banner that animates on and off the screen. I test it for being visible, and that works. But I can't seem to test its content.

Here's the element

```
  const errorStr = error && `ERROR: ${ error.message } (${ error.code })`;
  const warningStr = warning && `NOTIFICATION: ${ warning }.`;

<Transition in={ !!(error || warning) } timeout={ 0 }>{ state =>
  <Wrapper style={ transitionStyles[state] } data-testid={ 'ErrorBanner' }>
    {/*<div data-testid={'BannerError'} children={ errorStr }/>*/ }
    <div data-testid={ 'BannerError' } data-error={ error?.code }>{ errorStr }</div>
    <div data-testid={ 'BannerNotification' } children={ warningStr }/>
  </Wrapper>
}</Transition>
```

Here's my method that I call from my test to test it:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("getByTestId", str => cy.get(`[data-testid=${ str }]`));

const expectBanner = (message?: string | RegExp) => {
  cy.getByTestId('ErrorBanner').should('be.visible');
  if (!message) return
  cy.getByTestId('BannerError').then(el => {
    console.log(el);
    console.log(el[0]);
    const text = el[0].textContent;
    expect(text).to.eq(message);
  });
};
```

You'll notice that in the `then` block I log the `el` and `el[0]`.

[image]

When I expand that first property (`>0: div`), the innerHTML and textContent properties both show the text I expect. Same is true when I click on the passing assertion about it being visible.

But the test fails with `expected '' to be [whatever text I wanted]`. And as you can see in the picture, printing `el[0]` comes back as an empty div.

I've indeed tried `cy.contains` and `cy.getByTestId(message).contains` and none of those worked so I tried this more explicit route.

What is wrong?

Comment: Change `.then()` to `.should()` to allow Cypress to retry the `expect()`. Console log has lazy evaluation, value shown is likely to be after the transition (probably has an icon to tell you this).

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem may be with saving the value to the `const text`.
What if you tried:

```
cy.wrap(el[0].textContent).should('eq', message)
```

If that doesn't work, try this one (works for me):

```
  cy.getByTestId('BannerError').invoke('text').then((errorText) => {
     cy.wrap(errorText).should('eq', message)
  });
```

Let me know if it helps!